# AWS - websites, ftp, ssh stopped working after inappropriate command

Tags: amazon-web-services

I accidentally destroyed my EC2 (Amazon Linux 2023) instance after running inappropriate command:

```
sudo yum install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config
```

before running the above command, everything was fine. While executing the command, it crashed and now I can't connect via SSH, the websites stopped working and I can't connect via FTP etc...

I still have access to AWS Management Console (EC2 Instance Connect)

Any tips how to check what is wrong and fix my mistake.

I cant see anything useful in Log:

```
iplogin: [  284.738734] kauditd_printk_skb: 75 callbacks suppressed
[  284.738738] audit: type=1305 audit(1697559531.773:308): op=set audit_pid=0 old=1750 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
[  284.755919] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.793:309): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=auditd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.770845] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.793:310): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-setup comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.830509] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.853:311): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-remount-fs comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.842459] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.853:312): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-fsck-root comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.853193] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.853:313): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.863654] audit: type=1130 audit(1697559531.853:314): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-reboot comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.873538] audit: type=1131 audit(1697559531.853:315): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-reboot comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[  284.884715] audit: type=1334 audit(1697559531.853:316): prog-id=33 op=UNLOAD
[  284.888404] audit: type=1334 audit(1697559531.853:317): prog-id=32 op=UNLOAD
[  285.015718] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[  285.048590] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[  285.055048] systemd-journald[1045]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[  285.085033] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[  285.090500] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[  285.095979] (sd-remount)[3312]: Remounting '/' read-only with options 'seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,sunit=1024,swidth=1024,noquota'.
[  285.122256] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[  285.129250] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[  285.136976] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[  285.140078] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[  285.144571] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[  285.148991] systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices.
[  285.153713] systemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped.
[  285.156436] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[  285.159667] systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
[  285.163285] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems, swaps, loop devices, MD devices and DM devices detached.
[  285.177921] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[  285.185466] systemd-shutdown[1]: Rebooting.
[  285.211862] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
[  285.216252] reboot: Restarting system
[  285.219097] reboot: machine restart
[    3.323068] systemd[1]: Finished nfs-convert.service - Preprocess NFS configuration convertion.
[    3.337804] systemd[1]: Started systemd-journald.service - Journal Service.
[    3.358243] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[    3.456474] systemd-journald[1055]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    3.863652] vif vif-0 enX0: renamed from eth0
[    3.917240] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
[    4.155356] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[    4.157973] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
[    4.130144] rm[1781]: removed '/var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished'
[    4.143513] rm[1781]: removed '/var/lib/cloud/instance'
[    4.202386] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    4.478651] ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPF]
[    4.602774] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    4.607787] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    4.611795] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    4.615279] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    4.981113] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    5.105306] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    5.239118] ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: version 2.13
[    5.262739] systemd-sysv-generator[1862]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/cfn-hup' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    5.290450] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    5.290471] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    5.318586] scsi host0: ata_piix
[    5.363999] scsi host1: ata_piix
[    5.364462] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc100 irq 14
[    5.364464] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc108 irq 15
[    7.383039] cloud-init[2282]: Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'init' at Tue, 17 Oct 2023 16:19:31 +0000. Up 7.30 seconds.
[    7.422443] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[    7.435545] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    7.462085] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |          Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
[    7.480246] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    7.500266] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |  enX0  | True |        IP      | 255.255.240.0 | global | 02:3c:62:d5:5a:fd |
[    7.520269] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |  enX0  | True | ADDRESS |       .       |  link  | 02:3c:62:d5:5a:fd |
[    7.541306] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |         127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
[    7.560250] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |          ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
[    7.580239] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[    7.600256] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[    7.608704] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    7.628706] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: | Route | Destination |  Gateway   |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
[    7.650242] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    7.670236] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | IP |     0.0.0.0     |    enX0   |   UG  |
[    7.679610] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   1   |  IP |  0.0.0.0   |  255.255.240.0  |    enX0   |   U   |
[    7.700229] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   2   |  IP |  0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    enX0   |   UH  |
[    7.720234] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   3   |  IP |  0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    enX0   |   UH  |
[    7.728568] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[    7.750242] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
[    7.770321] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[    7.782867] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
[    7.802037] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[    7.820262] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   0   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
[    7.838939] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   2   |    local    |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
[    7.860402] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: |   3   |  multicast  |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
[    7.875718] cloud-init[2282]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[    9.740057] cloud-init[2355]: Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 17 Oct 2023 16:19:33 +0000. Up 9.61 seconds.
[   10.713923] cloud-init[2361]: Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 17 Oct 2023 16:19:34 +0000. Up 10.58 seconds.
[   10.820083] cloud-init[2361]: Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 finished at Tue, 17 Oct 2023 16:19:34 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 10.81 seconds


Amazon Linux 2023
```

Comment: Have you rebooted the server since that happened? And if so, did you check if the server's IP address changed?

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't realize that the IP could change.
I tried to "revert" that command, update the system, etc... but I didn't think of it. Thanks!